# How many days does it take to accumulate x inches for everyday?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a snapshot of my dataframe. It goes on for another 60+ years. The only thing I done is set my index as the **DATE** column.

```
            PRCP
DATE            
1950-01-01  0.00
1950-01-02  0.00
1950-01-03  0.08
1950-01-04  0.00
1950-01-05  0.00
1950-01-06  0.00
1950-01-07  0.21
1950-01-08  0.00
1950-01-09  0.00
1950-01-10  0.55
1950-01-11  0.00
1950-01-12  0.00
1950-01-13  0.15
1950-01-14  0.00
1950-01-15  0.00
1950-01-16  0.00
1950-01-17  0.00
1950-01-18  0.20
1950-01-19  0.00
```

What I would like to do is accumulate the **PRCP** column until it reaches a value greater than or equal to 1.0. Once it reaches this I want it to do to the same for the next date.

For example it would look something like this witht the date in one column and the number of days it took to reach 1.0 in the second column. The numbers I am using below are not exact (aside from the first date), but the pattern would be along these lines.:

```
            Days to Reach 1.0
DATE
1950-01-01  18
1950-01-02  6
1950-01-03  2
1950-01-04  20
1950-01-05  5
1950-01-06  1
1950-01-07  14
```

Once I have this, I will then do a simple...

```
groupby(df.index.dayofyear).mean()
```

so the final product would be...

```
DayOfYear   Days to Reach 1.0
01          9
02          20
03          12
04          14
...
365         14
366         12
```

Comment: Your intermediate values are inconsistent with your description. 18, 6, 2, 20, 5, and 14 are all larger than 1. What do you actually want that intermediate calculation to show? And how?

Comment: I have made some changes to help clarify. Note that the first dataframe is the only "real" data. The others are mearly examples to help understand the pattern that I am looking to find.

Comment: You could compute cumulative sum, group on the integer part of the result and count. Might need extra work to treat edge cases and spillovers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, I tried a different, more basic approach. It may not be efficient but here it is.

```
    depth_list = [1.0,4.0,10.0,20.0]        # various threshold depths to reach.
    df_j = pd.DataFrame(df['DATE'])         # creating an empty dataframe with DATE as the index
    for d in depth_list:
        j_list = []                         # starting an empty list for each threshold depth
        count1 = 0                          # adding in a 365 day counter assuming it does not take more than a year to accumulate.
        count2 = 366
        for i in df['DATE']:                # looping through i values after looping through Precipitation values from count1 to count2
            j_sum = 0                       # reset sums
            j_count = 0
            for j in df['PRCP'][count1:count2]:  
                j_count = j_count + 1
                j_sum = j_sum + j
                if j_sum >= d:              # Checking if value is greater than threshold.
                    j_list.append(j_count)
                    break                   # break out of loop when value is reached.
            count1 += 1
            count2 += 1
        
        df_j[d] = pd.DataFrame(j_list)          # Putting list into a dataframe with dates as the index knowing they are the same length
    df_join = df_j.set_index('DATE')    
    df_daymean = df_join.groupby(df_join.index.dayofyear).mean()        # Grouping by day of the year and taking the mean.
    print(df_daymean)
```

For a dataframe that looks like this...

```
           1.0        4.0        10.0        20.0
DATE                                             
1     11.928571  39.385714  91.371429  168.985714
2     11.971429  39.400000  91.185714  168.800000
3     11.728571  39.314286  91.100000  168.300000
4     11.871429  38.771429  90.528571  168.442857
5     11.900000  39.014286  90.528571  168.371429
        ...        ...        ...         ...
362   11.485714  40.115942  90.956522  170.159420
363   11.314286  40.101449  91.217391  169.927536
364   12.257143  40.318841  91.956522  169.637681
365   12.681159  39.913043  92.202899  169.260870
366   14.941176  44.176471  97.352941  174.529412
```